# How to better display this plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to produce the attached file.[image]

My question is how can I use R+ggplot2 in order to make this plot less busy and easier to see what is going on in the data? There are about 1000 observations and each observation has between 1 and 15 data points. I connect the observations with >1 datapoint with lines.

Is there maybe something to be done with the color scheme? Or possibly grouping things together?

My code looks something like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(variable, value, group=Name, color=Name))+
geom_point(alpha=.2, size=5)+
geom_line()+
geom_text(aes(label=Name),hjust=0, vjust=0, size=2)
```

Comment: Before you can know how to show it you have to think about what it is you're trying to show or at the very least examine.

Comment: It may also be that faceting will present this complicated data set more efficiently.

Comment: I am interested in seeing the overall trends in the lines. I do think that producing tons of plots based on different sample restrictions would help.

Comment: @lawyeR, I haven't used faceting in R before. Could you please explain what this would get me?

Comment: Do you really need to know *which* individual each of ~1000 lines corresponds to? Unless you are trying to do diagnostics (i.e. pick out the weird individuals), I would probably get rid of the labels, get rid of the colours (use the `group` aesthetic instead to get lines by individual), and use partially transparent lines (e.g. `alpha=0.3`) to get a sense of how many lines are overlapping.  As @TylerRinker says, though, hard to advise on how to plot the data when we don't know what questions you're trying to answer.

Comment: Facets are part of ggplot2.  They create multiple panels that have the same structure but vary by a variable.  It is a huge topic, not subject to the tiny limits of comments.  Do some reading on line.  Mostly, figure out what you want to say with the data.

Comment: Great suggestions all. I used facets and split it up by how many years I have data for that person. this allows me to get about 18 different plots and isolates the trends much better. Removing the names gets rid of some of the clutter as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any advice can be given you need to determine what data you want to group together. Perhaps you can group your data by gender/age. This can be done by changing 'color = Name' into 'color = Gender' if that column exists in your data.

The color scheme can be changed with scale_brewer. However, in every palette there are limited colors available so it will not be possible to have a distinct different color for each individual. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_brewer.html

If you want, your legend can also be changed in multiple columns with

```
+ guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

You can also change your theme options with

```
axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -330)
```

To turn your x-axis which will make it readable.